# Hola. El problema es el siguiente:tiene que imprimir por pantalla con un bucle while la siguiente serie en una lista 1, 50, 3, 48, 5, 46, ..., 0

Tags: python

Esto es lo que tengo ahora mismo, yo he pensado en que el num1 sea empezando por el 1 y que vaya aumentando los impares y el num2 que empiece por 50 y vaya disminuyendo contando los pares hasta el 0

```
def serie_numeros (numeros):
    
    while True:
        try:
            num1 = 1
            num2 = 50
            numeros = [num1 , num2]
            if (num1 in range(1,50) and not num1 % 2 == 0) and (num2 in range(50,0) and num2 % 2 == 0):
                num1 += 2
                num2 -= 2
    
                print(serie_numeros(numeros))

            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Incorrecto")
```

Comment: Pon en el título cuál es realmente el problema, y a tu título actual muévelo al cuerpo de la pregunta. Además, para corregir el formato de tu código, enciérralo entre triples tildes graves (```).

Answer (score 1):

Solución:

```
for i in range(0, 51, 2):
    print(f"{i + 1},{50 - i}", end=",")
```

El `for`recorre 0, 2, 4, ..., 50. En cada iteración imprimo dos valores:

- `i + 1`, que genera 1, 3, 5, ...
- `50 - i`, que genera 50, 48, 47, ...

produce:

```
1,50,3,48,5,46,7,44,9,42,11,40,13,38,15,36,17,34,19,32,21,30,23,28,25,26,27,24,29,22,31,20,33,18,35,16,37,14,39,12,41,10,43,8,45,6,47,4,49,2,51,0,
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que vuelves a "resetear" el valor de los número, es decir que al terminar el bucle tus variables `num1` y `num2` vuelven a tomar los valores iniciales, la solución se ponerlos fuera del `while`. Otra cosa es que no hace falta un `try/except` y tampoco ese `if` tan largo.

```py
def serie_numeros():
    num1 =0
    num2 = 50
    serie = []
    while True:
        num1+=2
        num2-=2
        if num1>=50 and num2<=0: break
        serie += [num1,num2]
    return serie #retornamos la lista de números
```

Comment: Y la función donde la utilizaría?

Comment: donde quieras, solo hacer `print(serie_numeros())`

Comment: me acabo de dar cuenta que le estas pasando un parámetro que no hace nada, así que lo quitas